# C# Websockets send serialized list to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

Hello I have a websockets server that sends a message from C# Server to Javascript Client (List serialized with `JavaScriptSerializer`)

I got the wanted input but I can't access the values of given item on list.

For example, I want to get ID value like so:

```js
function onMessage(evt) {
    JSON.parse(evt.data);
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data + '</span>' + evt.data[1].id + evt.data.id);
    websocket.close();
}
```

```cs
var users = LoadTables();
string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(users);
session.Send(output);
```

Output (id's are undefined):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not using parsed data.

You need to access data you have parsed using `JSON.parse`:

```js
function onMessage (evt) {
  let parsedData = JSON.parse(evt.data)
  // ...
  console.log(parsedData[1].id) // It should be 2 according to your output screenshot
}
```

Comment: Thank you, You Rock! It says 2 .How to display the whole data now? cause when i try to parsedData it displays ```RESPONSE: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]```

Comment: That's because it is an object converted to a string. You need to access specific properties of the object.

Comment: I just use a loop?